# How to ScriptControl AddCode() in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm using this code in C#:

```
    MSScriptControl.ScriptControl script = new MSScriptControl.ScriptControl();
    script.Language = "Javascript";
    script.Reset();
    script.AddCode(); // This line is my problem.
```

I want using this code in RSA.js:

```
    function createRsaKey(id, pw, sessionKey, keyName, eValue, nValue)
    {
      var rsa = new RSAKey();
      rsa.setPublic(eValue, nValue);

      var comVal = getLenChar(sessionKey) + sessionKey + getLenChar(id) + id;
      return rsa.encrypt(comVal + getLenChar(pw) + pw);
    }
```

Would you tell me, How to write code at script.AddCode. Please :)

Comment: Did you try `script.AddCode("function createRsaKey(...) { ... }")` ?

Comment: Lasse // Yeah! I'm tried to your way. But, Show this exception, "NotSupportedException". How can I this situation ?